# Understanding the difference between API, system call and system call interface

Tags: operating-systems

as anticipated in the title, I can't understand the difference between API, system call and system call interface.
Most of all, I can't understand if the **system call interface** is actually a "translator" between functions of an API and specific system call or if it is something else.

Comment: API is an abstract program interface, it is an abstract notion that specifies which functions inside a program to "expose" and allow other programs to use

Comment: system call are functions the operating system exposes for you to use as a user. For example, opening and writing to a file is something you need the help of the operating system to do - and as such it will use system calls

Comment: The *system call interface* is the "API" of the *operating system*, simply.